# Direct proof for sequential characterisation of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, solution-verification

This question has been posted several times, but given convergence to show continuity are using contrapositive by letting $f$ not being continuous. I am looking for a direct proof that given convergence proves continuity.

[image]

**My original attempt.** Given convergence statement we know $|f(x_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon_1 ,\forall n>N_1$ whenever $|x_n-a|<\epsilon_2,\forall n>N_2$. Pick an $n>N$ which satisfies $\delta<\epsilon_2$, then it becomes exactly the same as the definition of continuity at $a$.

**Is this proof correct?**

My question is why do I need to find out $\delta$ in terms of $n$, in proving convergence given continuity, it also need not to find out exact $N$?

Appreciate for any help and comments.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Much appreciate if you could check my question

Answer (score -1):

$|f(x_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon_1 ,\forall n>N_1$ whenever $|x_n-a|<\epsilon_2,\forall n>N_2$.

Now given any $\epsilon >0$

You have to choose some $\delta >0 $ neighborhood around $a$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$ whenever $|x-a| < \delta$

Now $\{x \in \mathbb R : |x-a|< \delta\}$ is an uncountable set and points of sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $|x_n-a|< \delta$ are countable.

So you have to consider collection of all sequences $y_n$ which converges to $a$ such that $\{x \in \mathbb R : |x-a|< \delta\}=\bigcup_{n \in I}\{ y_n^{(i)} : | y_n^{(j)} -a| < \delta \}$ , Here $I$ is suitable indexing set.

It is easy to prove continuity argument for fixed $y_n^{(i)}$

Hence prove for $\bigcup_{n \in I}\{  y \in y_n^{(i)} : | y_n^{(j)} -a| < \delta \}$

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am not sure this $\bigcup_{n \in I}\{  y \in y_n^{(i)} : | y_n^{(j)} -a| < \delta \}$, is $y_n^{j}$ indicating the $j$-th term? Then it's not make sense for $y\in y_n^{i}$ . what do you think about **my attempt** proof, do you think that appropriate?

Comment: fine, i edited. actually i want to consider all elements of sequences which satisfy the given condition